# Modifying email on an existing account

Tags: support, profile-page, email

My email is an old one and no longer exists.  How can I update my email address on my account?  I don't see a 'user profile' page for this site.  Is there one?

Answer (score 5):

There is a 'profile page.' Click the button right next to 'help' at the top:

[image: user profile]

(Be sure to do this [on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current), NOT here on meta!)

There should be a 'settings' button on that profile page.

[image: Edit profile and settings]

Click that and then scroll down to "private information" and edit your email address:

[image]

Now, if you're using the old email to log in, you'll have to change that also. This gets a bit more complicated; please see: [How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)